# Does MockRestServiceServer support mutual TLS and if so, how to configure it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mutual-authentication

We use `org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer` in our IT tests to verify our `RestTemplate` handling. Now, I need to include also some tests for mutual authentication and I'm not sure if this is possible and how to achieve that. Does `MockRestServiceServer` support that or do I need to go for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I haven't found a way, I went for com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer which works pretty good. Here is how I set it up, please note that I needed to add keyManagerPassword as well (I'm not sure why, but it's simply the one of the keystore)

```
  public WireMockServer mutualTlsMock;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    mutualTlsMock = new WireMockServer(options()
      .httpsPort(8443)
      .needClientAuth(true)
      .keystorePath("path/to/my/keystore.jks")
      .keystorePassword("keystorePassword")
      .keyManagerPassword("keystorePassword")
      .trustStorePath("path/to/my/keystore.jks")
      .trustStorePassword("keystorePassword"));
    mutualTlsMock.start();
  }

  @AfterEach
  void shutdown() {
    mutualTlsMock.shutdown();
  }
```